# ¿Como generar esta validacion en laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-7

Buen dia, estoy tratando de realizar esta validación:

```
$data = request()->validate([
            "FechaEsperada" => 'required | date',
            "arribo" => 'required|in:SI,NO',
            "FechaReal" => 'required_if:arribo,SI|after_or_equal:FechaEsperada'  ,
 ]);
```

arribo es un grupo de radio buttons, con las opciones SI y NO. si esta seleccionado SI, debe permitir colocar la fecha real, pero  asi como tengo el codigo , si selecciono NO aun asi me pide que coloque la fecha, sale este mensaje "FechaReal debe ser una fecha posterior o igual a FechaEsperada".
quisiera saber en que estoy mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema puede ser que el campo `FechaReal` está presente en el request, aún si tiene un valor `null` o una fecha que no pase la validación `after_or_equal:FechaEsperada`, que aunque no esté marcada como requerida, la regla se aplicará si el campo está presente.

Entonces debes especificar que excluya la validación de ese campo cuando el valor del campo `arribo` sea igual a `NO`.
Puedes hacerlo con la regla [exclude_if](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exclude-if):

```
$data = request()->validate([
    "FechaEsperada" => 'required|date',
    "arribo" => 'required|in:SI,NO',
    "FechaReal" => 'required_if:arribo,SI|exclude_if:arribo,NO|date|after_or_equal:FechaEsperada'  ,
]);
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono perfecto.